# Convert double and integer to currency in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I followed this code but I didn't get the correct answer

```
print('1234512.00'.replaceAllMapped(new RegExp(r'(\d{1,2})(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))'), (Match m) => '${m[1]},'));
```

output : **1,234,512.00**

but I want  12,34,512

*Example*:

*100000* => **1,00,000**

*7446016.38* => **74,46,016.38**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you want to format **Indian rupee** value.

For simplicity - go with the [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) package and it's **NumberFormat** class which can also format currencies.

Install it, import in to your code and use as follows:

```dart
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

final formatter = NumberFormat.currency(
      locale: 'hi_IN',
      decimalDigits: 2,
      symbol: '',
    );
final formattedValue = formatter.format(num.parse('1234512.01'));

print(formattedValue);
```

---

Additional formatter that will remove **.00** at the end of the line:

```dart
final formatter = NumberFormat('##,##,###.##');
    final formattedValue = formatter.format(num.parse('11111111000.001'));
```

**1111000.001** will become **11,11,000**
**1111000.01** will become **11,11,000.01**